# Backups of RSA public and private keys

Tags: key, backup, rsa

I was wondering which is the best way of making a backup of RSA key pairs. I have them in the same server I use to make backups in order to encrypt and by now this is a SPOF. I can't find any good solution googling around.

Answer (score 0):

Save the key pair into a password-protected [key store](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.IBMDI.doc_7.1%2Fadminguide36.htm).